# Uniform convergence for series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Given the series:$\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^2 \cos (2x)}{1+k^4x^6} $ show that the series converge uniformly.

I tried to do it like this:
$$\frac{x^2 \cos (2x)}{1+k^4x^6}  \le \frac{x^2 }{1+k^4x^6}  \\ \text{Atvasina pēc } x \text{ un pielīdzina nullei: } \frac{2x(1+k^4x^6) -x^2 (6k^4x^6) }{(1+k^4x^6)^2} = 0 \\ x(2+2k^4x^6-6k^4x^7) = 0 \Rightarrow x_1 = 0 \\ x(k^4x^5-3k^4x^6)=-1 \Rightarrow x_2 = -1 \\ x^5(k^4-3k^4x) = 0 \Rightarrow x_3 = -\frac{1}{3} \\ f''_k =\frac{(2+2k^4x^6+12x^6-26k^4x^7-36k^4x^7)(1+k^4x^6)-(2x(1+k^4x^6) -x^2 (6k^4x^6)) 6k^4x^5}{1+k^4x^6} \\ f''_k(0) = 2 > 0 \Rightarrow \text{ nav max} \\ f''_k(-1) = (2+4k^4+24 +52k^4 +72k^4) (1+2k^4) -(12k^4+24k^8-2\cdot 1296k^8) > 0 \\$$

But the way I do it, it looks clumsy and no point is max. Then what could be another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $x^2\cos{(2x)}$ can be pulled out of the summation since the index of the summation is $k$.  You're left with $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+k^4x^6}$, where x is treated as a constant.  Compare the summation to $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^4x^6}$, which is larger than the original summation.  The summation $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^4x^6}$ converges from the integral test or p-series test for $x\neq0$.  By direct comparison test, the original summation converges.  And for the case when $x=0$ the the summation turns into $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 0$ which converges.

Comment: But how is it given that the multiplication of $x^2 \cos (2x)$ with the series will be less than series $\frac{1}{k^4x^6}$?

Comment: I just didn't type the $x^2\cos{(2x)}$ for the series I compared it with, my bad.

Comment: @Ok, that was dumb. When I try to prove the convergence of the series $\frac{1}{k^4x^6}$ do I treat $x$ as a constant? I am not sure if this is comlete proof: $\frac{1}{y^6}(-4) \left[  \frac{1}{x^5}\right]^{\infty}_1 = 0  +\frac{4}{y^6}  < \infty \ \ \forall y \in R $

Comment: The index of the series  is still k, so yes treat x as a constant still.  The integral of $\frac{1}{k^4x^6}$ (with respect to k) from 1 to $\infty$ is $\frac{-1}{3k^3x^6}\big\rvert_1^{\infty}=\boxed{\frac{1}{3x^6}}$.  This converges for $x \neq 0$ so the comparison hold for $x \neq 0$, and to see if the initial series converges at $x=0$ plug $x=0$ into the original series to get 0.